# Flutter & Dart: What the function that can get a List by adding an item (front or behind) for every item in another List?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `List<Widget>` assume a name is `fields`.
I want to show `fields` in `Column` like:

```
Column(
      children: [
        ...fields,
      ],
    )
```

But I want to add a `SizedBox()` for every widget in `fields`.(Not `Padding()` or other widget)

At the moment, I am using something like:

```
Column(
      children: [
        ...[
          for (int index = 0; index < fields.length * 2; index++)
            index % 2 == 0 ? fields[index ~/ 2] : SizedBox()
        ],
      ],
    )
```

But I want something like `fileds.mapWithAdding((e)=>[e,SizedBox()]).toList()`

Does `Flutter` or `Dart` currently have this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably `.expand(...)`.

So, something like this in your case:

```
children: [
  ...fields.expand((x) => [x, const SizedBox(height: 5)])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to point out that your approach needlessly wraps collection-`for` in an inner `List` only to use the spread operator to expand it immediately afterward.  That is:

> ```dart
> Column(
>       children: [
>         ...[
>           for (int index = 0; index < fields.length * 2; index++)
>             index % 2 == 0 ? fields[index ~/ 2] : SizedBox()
>         ],
>       ],
>     )
> ```

could be slightly simplified to:

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        for (int index = 0; index < fields.length * 2; index++)
          index % 2 == 0 ? fields[index ~/ 2] : SizedBox()
      ],
    )
```

Another approach would be to use [`IterableZip`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableZip-class.html) and [`flattened`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableIterableExtension/flattened.html) from [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) to interleave two lists:

```dart
Column(
  children: IterableZip(
    fields,
    List.filled(fields.length, const SizedBox()),
  ).flattened.toList(),
),
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for another method. For my example, I have another widget in Column so I using [ ...[ ] ]